# Select with ability to create new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm searching the right solution for such functionality:

1. We have model `Book` that has belongs to `Author`
2. When creating new book we can select an author from existing.
3. Under the select input there is a link 'Create new author'.
4. On clicking this link modal window appears with form for author (`:name`, `:biography`, `:picture` etc.).
5. After submitting the form the author is created and available for selection.

Don't want someone to write ready code for me, but I would be very grateful if someone tells me the right way to solve this issue

Comment: Sounds fine, just start to implement your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `Book` model

```
belongs_to :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
```

Now in your controller you need to permit the params for `author_id` and `author_attributes`

If you add `:name, :biography, :picture` attributes to `author_attributes` then it will create a new author and save new `author_id` in your `Book` instance.

If you specify `author_id` then do not specify `author_attributes`.

Sample params sent to controller

```
{ "book":
   {"name": "Sample Book Title", 
    "author_attributes": 
       { name: "John Doe", biography: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sir Amet", 
         picture: "xxx.png"}
   }
}
```

which will create a new user
or this

```
{ "book":
   {"name": "Sample Book Title", 
    "author_id": 2
   }
}
```

which will assign author with id 2 to the book.

Good luck.